# FInd Javascript Error In IE 7?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I had Put a digg button in my blog. The blog runs fine on firefox and opera,but when i open it in ie7 it shows javascript error.clicking on that little triangle doesn't show any information..how to remove that error?

Comment: You need to be more specific, an example would be nice.

Comment: I recall that their was a Firebug.js script available to debug Javascript on IE7. Maybe this could help you dig into the error a little bit more.

Comment: You should try the (free) [Fiddler2 for Internet Explorer](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) tool. It gives you a range of additional information for scripts and the background goings on of your code etc, might make it easier to find exactly what and where the error is.

Comment: ok i'll try it.thanks for the info

Comment: Nothing like having illegal book downloads linked on your blog.

Answer (score 1):

try to search for Firebug Lite on Google. This is a version of Firebug that can be directly integrated into the webpage and allows so to have the great Firebug features also on IE.
It may help to find your JavaScript problem.